# Cannot consume WCF Rest Services in WCF Client

Tags: wcf, datacontractserializer

I have a Service and the releated interface under namespace called "WCFService":

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBook
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="GET"
        ,ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json
        ,BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped
        ,UriTemplate="/?bookID={bookID}")]
    Book Get(int bookID);
}

//========================================================

 public Book Get(int bookID)
 {
     return bookList.Where(p => p.BookID == bookID).FirstOrDefault();  
 }
```

And the Book DataModel is under another namespace called "WCFModel":

```
[DataContract]
public class Book
{
    [DataMember]
    public int BookID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string BookName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public decimal BookPrice { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string BookPublish { get; set; }
}
```

After set the config file, I got the service run ok.
Then I planned to consume it in client side. I added a windows form application to the project and added reference to the WCFModel book datamodel, I used below code to extract the data:

```
    string serviceURL = "http://localhost:15020/BookService.svc/?bookID=" + txtBookID.Text.Trim();
    var request = WebRequest.Create(serviceURL);
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(WCFModel.Book));
    var bookObj = serializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
```

But the result was, VS thrown me an exception at the ReadObject below:

```
Error when deserializing the WCFModel.Book  type, Data at the root level is invalid.
```

stack trace below：

```
在 System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
在 System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
在 System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement()
在 System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement(XmlDictionaryString localName, XmlDictionaryString namespaceUri)
在 System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator.IsStartElement(XmlDictionaryString localname, XmlDictionaryString ns)
在 System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.IsRootElement(XmlReaderDelegator reader, DataContract contract, XmlDictionaryString name, XmlDictionaryString ns)
在 System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalIsStartObject(XmlReaderDelegator reader)
在 System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
在 System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
```

I don't know why, After searching a lot, I still can't get the point. Anyone can give me some reference? thx.

Comment: Might be a strange question but why making restful if your going to then consume data contract ? the whole goal of restful is to call blindly already knowing the return format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this may work for you!
Try implementing this!

```
WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
string serviceURL = 
       string.Format("http://localhost:15020/BookService.svc/?bookID=" + txtBookID.Text.Trim().ToString()); 
 byte[] data = proxy.DownloadData(serviceURL);
 Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
 DataContractJsonSerializer obj = 
                    new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Book));
 Book book = obj.ReadObject(stream) as Book;
 Console.WriteLine("Book ID : " + book.BookID);
 Console.WriteLine("Book Name : " + book.BookName);
 Console.WriteLine("Book ID : " + book.BookPrice);
 Console.WriteLine("Book ID : " + book.BookPublish);
```

See this [link](http://dotnetmentors.com/wcf/wcf-rest-service-to-get-or-post-json-data-and-retrieve-json-data-with-datacontract.aspx)

**EDIT:** Change `BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped` to `BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare`.

Comment: I got an empty book, BookID is 0, Book Name is null, BookPrice is 0 and BookPublish is null.

Comment: I finally get it worked to set : BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, thx.

Comment: Right! Good research :)

Comment: Let me edit the answer so that if anyone read it, he/she may take benefit from it.

Comment: here I posted an article about it http://www.cnblogs.com/scy251147/p/3566638.html